# How do i resolve this problem: "array out of range in 'Price.mqh' (57,12)"?

Tags: mql5

input ulong Slippage = 3;

Above code is what am having on line 57. The code is from an EA and i experienced this problem on Volatility 50 Index.

Comment: you should check the file Price.mqh not the executable .mq4 file for the error

Comment: Thank you i never thought of that.